# jquery slider update not working

Tags: jquery, slider

I cant get this fiddle to work:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lr57Lq0z/

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
function updateAmounts() {  
var value1 = $('#slider1').slider('value');  
var value2 = $('#slider2').slider('value');
```

See the rest in the fiddle.

When the to sliders are moved, the script works.

But if you type an amount and click the next input, it dosn't update.
And if you push the slider line (and not the handle) as the first thing, there is no reaction in script og in the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind change event with your inputs. Also you should use `change` event of slider.

```
$('#amount1').on('change', function(){
    $('#slider1').slider( "value", $(this).val() ).slider('refresh'); 
    updateAmounts();
});
$('#amount2').on('change', function(){
    $('#slider2').slider( "value", $(this).val() ).slider('refresh');   
    updateAmounts();
});

$('#slider2, #slider1').slider({
    value: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 200,
    step: 1,
    change: function () {
        updateAmounts();
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fL6nfsvy/)